# How to active second tab instead of first one using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project, where I want to show a second tab active on window load, but it always active the first tab.

Here is my script:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tabs div').hide();
    $('#tabs div:first').show();
    $('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');
    $('#tabs ul li a').click(function() {
        $('#tabs ul li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#tabs div').hide();
        $(currentTab).show();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

The problem is, when I write second in place of first it doesn't work.

Comment: Try using `$('#tabs ul li').eq(1).addClass('active')` instead

Comment: And also `$('#tabs div').eq(1).show();`

Comment: i tried this, and it works only for tabs, but i also want to show the content under active tab. which doesn't appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `show` and `hide` outside the click handler and repeating the logic, you can trigger the event for a specific `a` element:

```
var $a = $('#tabs ul li a').click(function() {
    $('#tabs ul li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#tabs div').hide();
    $(currentTab).show();
    return false;
});

$a.eq(1).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the JQuery `eq` method, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tabs div').hide();
    $('#tabs div').eq(1).show();
    $('#tabs ul li').eq(1).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: it works, but only for tabs, i also want to show the content under it. the div i want to show doesn't appear when the current tab is active,